# Cannot select date range in react-date-range plugin

Tags: reactjs, react-datepicker

I am using [react-date-range](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-date-range) plugin to select a date range in a application. It is shown as follows.

[image]

```
    export function Dashboard() {
    historyDate = [];
    historyAmount = [];

    const [dashboardSummary] = useDashboardSummary();

    const [a, fetchDashboardSummary] = useDashboardSummary();

    let [req, setReq] = useState<DashboardSummaryReqGqlInput>({
        startDate: start.format('YYYY-MM-DD'),
        endDate: end.format('YYYY-MM-DD')
    });

    useEffect(() => {
        fetchDashboardSummary({
            req
        });
    }, [req])

    $('#reportrange span').html(start.format('MMMM D, YYYY') + ' - ' + end.format('MMMM D, YYYY'));

    if (isSuccess(dashboardSummary)) {
        dailyTotalCount = dashboardSummary.result.dashboardSummary.dailyTxnCount;
        dailyValue = dashboardSummary.result.dashboardSummary.dailyTxnValue;
        dailySuccessCount = dashboardSummary.result.dashboardSummary.dailySuccessTxnCount;
        let historyData = dashboardSummary.result.dashboardSummary.amountHistory
        for(let x in historyData) {
            historyAmount.push(historyData[x].amount!)
            historyDate.push(historyData[x].date!)
        }
    }

    function setDateRange(startDate: Date, endDate: Date){
        console.log("setDateRange:  start:" , startDate + "   end:", endDate)
        console.log(moment(startDate).format("YYYY-MM-DD"))
        start = moment(startDate)
        end = moment(endDate)

        setReq({startDate: moment(startDate).format("YYYY-MM-DD"), endDate: moment(endDate).format("YYYY-MM-DD")})
    }

    const selectionRange = {
        startDate: new Date(),
        endDate: new Date(),
        key: 'selection',
    }

    function handleSelect(ranges: any) {
        setDateRange(ranges.selection.startDate, ranges.selection.endDate)
        showDateRangePicker = false
    }

    function onClickDateRangePicker() {
        console.log("--------onClickRangePicker")
        showDateRangePicker = true
        setReq({startDate: moment(start).format("YYYY-MM-DD"), endDate: moment(end).format("YYYY-MM-DD")})
    }

    return  <div className="container-fluid">
        <div className="row">

            <div className="col-lg-2 col-md-3 offset-lg-2 offset-md-3 second-sidebar">
                <p>Last Transactions</p>
                <RecentTransactions/>
            </div>
            <main role="main" className="col-lg-8 col-md-6 ml-sm-auto p-0">
                <div className="sub-header-dashboard">
                    <div className="row">
                        <div className="col-lg-6">
                            <h5 className="sub-text mt-lg-2 ml-md-0 ml-5">Dashboard</h5>
                        </div>

                        <div className="col-lg-6">
                            <div className="input-group">
                                <div className="input-group-prepend">
                                    <span className="input-group-text" onClick={onClickDateRangePicker}><i className="fas fa-calendar-alt"></i></span>

                                </div>
                                <div id={"date-picker-box"} style={{display: showDateRangePicker ? "block" : "none"}}>
                                    <DateRangePicker
                                        className={"datepicker"}
                                        ranges={[selectionRange]}
                                        onChange={handleSelect}/>
                                </div>
                                <div id="reportrange" className="form-control date-range-input pt-3">
                                    <span className="date-range-input__date"></span>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>                    
            </main>
        </div>
    </div>

}

export default Dashboard
```

I can select a date range by dragging but cannot select start and end date separately. When I click on  a date it selects that date as both start date and end date. Instead I want to select start and end date separately.
Is this is available in this pluging? Or Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Can you post your full component as this doesn't look like React. Where is your useState?

Comment: @Kurtis Post is updated with full component

Comment: It doesn't look like you are using the state object: `req`. The range passed in is hardcoded to `new Date()`. Have you tried the first code example from here:https://hypeserver.github.io/react-date-range/. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

You can attain the desired functionality in two ways.

1. Set `retainEndDateOnFirstSelection={true}`. This will let you select end date independent of the second click. Also set the following flag `moveRangeOnFirstSelection={false}`
2. Let the date inputs be editable. You can set `editableDateInputs={true}`.
   Hope this helps you.
   Happy Coding!